# Como incluir solo los datos que no se repiten a una lista

Tags: python, lista, csv

Necesito leer un archivo y crear una lista con lo que tiene adentro, el archivo dice lo siguiente:

```
10;central
11;Sur
10;Norte
```

Si el numero se repite no debo incluirlo  en la lista, como en este casa pasa con `Norte`.

Este es el código que escribí:

```
archivo=open("Sedes.txt","r")
sedes=[]
while(True):
    linea = archivo.readline()
    if not linea:
        break
    sedes=sedes+[linea]

print(sedes)
```

Esto crea una lista con todos los datos, pero incluye a los repetidos, ¿cómo puedo eliminar el dato que se repite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que usar un condicional que por cada línea leída buscara en la lista si el número existe. La búsqueda en listas es ineficiente porque en el peor de los casos tiene que recorrer toda la lista para confirmar que el elemento no existe..

En vez de usar una lista inicialmente es mucho más simple y eficiente usar un diccionario en el que la clave sea el número y el valor la linea:

```
with open("Sedes.txt") as archivo:
    sedes = {}
    for linea in archivo:
        num, _ = linea.split(";")
        if num not in sedes:
            sedes[num] = linea

sedes = list(sedes.values())
print(sedes)
```

> ['10;central\n', '11;Sur\n']

Algunas observaciones:

- Cierra siempre un archivo de forma explícita cuando termines con el. Est no es una tarea que deba relegarse al GC, usa el método `close` o mejor usa el administrador de contexto mediante `with`.
- No uses un ciclo `while` y `readline` para iterar sobre las lineas del fichero es mucho más eficiente y legible iterar sobre las lineas directamente con un ciclo `for in`.
- Para agregar un elemento a la lista no uses concatenado, esto es muy ineficiente ya que crea una lista temporal con un solo elemento que solo se usa para concatenarla. Usa `list.append` o `list.extend` en su lugar.